# Change selected option on an event in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and I'm trying to change the selected option of a select box on change of other select box.

So there are 2 select boxes like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select-01new" ng-model="applicationOption" ng-change="AppChange(applicationOption)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="act in applicationOptions" value="{{act._id}}">{{act.name}}</option>
</select>

<select data-ng-model="posture.Value" id="scurityPosture" data-ng-options="act as act for act in activities" class="form-control">                
</select>
```

Here is the controller:

```
 sampleApp.controller('CreateAppController', function ($scope, AppDataService) {
    $scope.posture = {
            name: "Dani",
            Value: "Low"
        };
        $scope.activities =
        [
            "High",
            "Medium",
            "Low"

        ];
$scope.AppChange = function () {
        AppDataService.save($scope.applicationOption).then(
            function (datac) { 
                $scope.posture = { name: "Dani", Value: "High" }; 
            });
    }

    });
```

You can see, there is `ng-change` on first select box. Whenever we will change the option of first select box, a function defined in controller will run. In that function, the value of second select box changes. But that part of the functionality does not work.

Please help me to sort it out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, preper a fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you change the first select box, AppChange method will be executed, triggering the 'Save' method in AppDataService. Here, the promise object gives access to the result of the AJAX call through 'then' method [(see $q service documentation)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q):

> then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback) – regardless of
>   when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one
>   of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result
>   is available.

In the controller above, you provide only the success callback, while you might have errors, and your success code won't be executed.

You should first check that the success callback is executed and after that debug further. My guess is you get some errors from the server and you never reach the success status.